# Typescript fluent api builder multiple parameters (override) not possible

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider the following class which is declared in a 3rd party library. I cannot modify this file.

```
declare class Foo<T> {
    methodA(foo: string): this 
    methodB(): this;
    methodD(): this;
    methodD(type: string): this;
}
```

The above class is a fluent api which can calls itself. The requirement is that `methodB` should never be callable. Therefore I created the following type which will be used over `Foo<T>`

```
type FooWithoutB<T> = Omit<Foo<T>, 'methodB'>
```

But this still allows me to do the following:

```
let typeWithoutB!: WithoutB<any>;

typeWithoutB.methodA('hello').methodB() // should not be possible
```

So I thought, ok, let's override the return type, thus I made this type:

```
type Override<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends (...param: any[]) => T ? (...params: Parameters<T[key]>) => WithoutB<T> : T[key]
}
```

The above almost works but breaks Parameter types:

```
foo.methodD() // expected one argument but got 0
foo.methodD('ok') // this works, but above should also work
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwGIHtMB4AqAfPAN4CwAUPFfALYgAuAFpsAIIAUAZtgFzzL0YASwB2AcwCUfJkLQVqtBs2AAhdlPgzkAbnnU6TFgBF10xrN2V9S4+3oBPAA4g+A4eI1bLAXwoUIDPDcmABMAIR8WLhQIvYEfuQA9InwjCBw8ACSiDE5EBCKhsBG8ADuQkzwmDBlFcwArjWOsFAG6RTBIQB0BsomEj02bOwA5FB5AcAjEh3Y3b22I6XVANbI04NFHGMTIFMz5BQOzvAA6nWY9fQq+EQAvPAA8jQVOFG3ADTwIwuqI-HkY4IR4AN3SwlAt3gDzIVioAG0ViB7PBRPAkfZMJx4HgALp8PCI5G4+AgAAe9BAImAaHYXXpzRgrT4MXs8NxEmhRDw8AA-PA6QyWjRkHwAArChjpZD4In2XEETl3IjnQxXG6EeAEuW4ii+Q7kAL0ILYCJPMEwCEgHDPV7vVkEL4-IYqf4ESwUZJZeAiEB7TSYeBwGiYMGFZQqL5aVFoUqMKDG0PgoSgTROBDATAgNDcGrIeoAIyBaBQZRA+S6npSeHMsdWJbQ5OcYEpwC+BauaecyDAwkcxuDSZLMDE9ToImNyCEYhECca2b4wU2fTs6dcglEkhjEygBYCXyXv3625EmGNYCg+V3AVmmGXLDUEm08C9vxUPrPO73CDjQjAjG3MRsGAW972KUZMBWDY33UZ9XxdD9z0vaBvzKcx-0A4DQKPdQXxSIFSUtao0L-ADZEQ0kyWbVt+FEMAEBwzkADJw1sIF13cLdyNECohEvIQAC9-UwEREGgVAMGwHAAWwoZtkg6C5IgqCBkYsDHzwk080wOggxAFARO9MRAgLKAwBWTQ0iqYQxFES8uwQQymAQABmGBgHgAIwQKGIPOc0SKjKet207bIL1Ei98lY1RcN-DDkAaCAPNPY0CwQRxMFQIRvyAA)

**Edit**

Found out that `type F = Parameters<Foo<any>['methodD']>` returns `[type: string]`. Is there an option to resolve both parameter types?

Comment: I think you might have bigger problems if there exist functions that should never be called.

Comment: 100% agree... Unfortunately using a 3rd party library that we cannot easily swap with something else.

Comment: have you considdered using a private function for methodB? your virtual methodD in typescript gets defined like that: methodD(type?: string): this

Comment: @Dieterg: Override needs to be recursive, by the way, so the returned type should be `Override<WithoutB<T>>` in the function case.

Comment: Looks like the overloads make this near impossible...

Comment: Yes, Im afraid it's not possible. Is there another option to infer the types? There are not many overloads. Thought to type them out by hand but no success so far..

Comment: Maybe, but i cannot think of anything. Mapped types tend to be the most powerful tool for things like this.

Comment: By the way, here is an [open issue regarding the overloads](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy answer here.  One possibility is to fall back on classic OOP and introduce a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).  So we'd wrap an instance of the existing class in a new class, and forward calls where appropriate.  Something like the code below.  Note that this assumes that our MethodA and MethodDs return 'this'.

```
class FooFacade<T>
{
    private _foo: Foo<T> = new Foo<T>();
    methodA(foo: string): this { this._foo.methodA(foo); return this; }
    
    methodD(): this;
    methodD(type: string): this;
    methodD(type?: string): this {
        if (type !== undefined) {
            this._foo.methodD(type);
        } else {
            this._foo.methodD();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The obvious drawback of this is it's a bit clunky and depending on how complex Foo actually is it could be a lot of work.  An advantage is it gives you complete control over how the third-party software is called.

Comment: Yes I think this is the only solution until overloads are supported.